# PHP Error: Base class function calls derived class

Tags: php, function, inheritance, parent, radix

I am writing an api in PHP.
I have got a base class which implemets the magic function `__call`:

```
class Controller
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if(!method_exists($this,$name))
            return false;
        else if(!$arguments)
            return call_user_func(array($this,$name));
        else
            return call_user_func_array(array($this,$name),$array);
    }
}
```

and a child class like this:

```
class Child extends Controller
{
    private function Test()
    {
        echo 'test called';
    }
}
```

so when i do this:

```
$child = new Child();
$child->Test();
```

and load the page it takes a lot of time and after a while the web browser prints that the page can't be requested. no output is given from php, only a web browser error.

apache error log (last part only):

```
...
[Tue Sep 24 12:33:14.276867 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1600:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3928
[Tue Sep 24 12:33:15.198920 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3928:tid 464] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Sep 24 12:33:15.287925 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3928:tid 464] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 24 12:38:43.366426 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1600:tid 452] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Tue Sep 24 12:38:43.522426 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 1600:tid 452] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
```

i can't find the mistake, but if the function Test is protected everything works fine.

solution found:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if(!method_exists($this,$name))
        return false;
    $meth = new ReflectionMethod($this,$name);
    $meth->setAccessible(true);
    if(!$arguments)
        return $meth->invoke($this);
    else
        return $meth->invokeArgs($this,$arguments);
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, your English is better than some native speakers I know.

Comment: you should only be able to call functions that are public outside of a class unless you are using reflections: http://php.net/reflectionmethod.setaccessible

Comment: This is **very** bad practice. Methods should be visible to the context from which they're being called. `__call()` shouldn't act as a proxy that's dynamically changing visibilities...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is an issue (bug?) documented in the [documentation of `method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php#61320): `method_exists()` returns true even if the method is private/protected and thus, not accessible from outside the class. This leads to infinite recursion in your case, as your `Child->Test()` call invokes `Child::__call()`, which checks whether `Test()` exists (it does, but can't be called), then tries to call it, which again leeds to `__call()` being invoked. Comments suggest using `get_class_methods()` might resolve the issue. I'm not sure why changing the visibility of `Test()` to `private` changes the behavior as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Give `Test()` public visibility, and it should work.

I'm not entirely sure why private visibility causes a 500 error (as opposed to `Call to private method...`), but I suspect it's to do with recursion involving the `__call()` function. Some features in PHP do more harm than good - do you really need it?

Comment: yea with public it works but my aim was to work around public :).